# Checking when a car horn is pressed?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, pic, microchip, automotive

I want to detect when a car horn is pressed. The only way I can detect it currently is using the voltage on its line.
When the car is turned on, there is always 12V being supplied to the horn through the battery i.e. When the horn is NOT being used the voltage to it is 12V.

When the horn is being used the line voltage drops between 2V-1V due to the consumption by the horn.
I was thinking of using the High/Low voltage detect module of the pic 18f4520 to detect this voltage drop when the horn is pressed. But the module seems to be more for detecting a drop in operational voltage. Is there a downside to using the HLDV in such a manner, also is there a better/other way to do this? Any code snippets to HLVD or other methods are greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and have a great day.

Comment: Obviously the horn is connected to 12V on one side and a relay or transistor to ground on the other side. Why don't you simply detect the voltage on that line ? It will be 12V when the horn is off and ground when it is on.

Comment: I might have a hard time thinking of a worse approach than using an **edge-triggered interrupt** on what will likely be a noisy and relatively small signal. **Really**, can't you just run a wire to the 'hot' side of that horn or the horn relay/switch/transistor? If not, maybe you could pick up the 800Hz or whatever ripple from the horn and do an FFT (not really a serious suggestion).

Comment: Why worry about the noisy voltages?  Couldn't you simply measure the current draw by voltage across a resistor?  I'm pretty sure that's how they do it within the auto industry anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're measuring the voltage with respect to ground, not across the horn terminals.  If so, what you are describing sounds like this:

[image: img1]

Except that the switch is likely a relay, MOSFET, SSR, or some other device that has a non-zero resistance even when "closed".

In this case, both wires across the horn will be at the battery voltage when the horn is off.  When the switch closes the bottom wire will drop towards ground and current will start to flow.  The reason it doesn't actually reach zero volts is because of the resistance of the switch.

It is important to realize that the top wire won't vary (much) from the battery voltage whether the horn is active or not.

You'll need to monitor the line between the horn and the switch.  To interface this to a PIC (or other microcontroller), you will need to scale the voltage so that it doesn't exceed the PIC's Vdd (probably 3.3V or 5V in your circuit).  You would do this by using a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider):

[image: img2]

Say that your Vdd is 5V.  Assume that the horn voltage swings from 15V to 2V.  If you divide the voltage by 3, the output swings from 5V to 0.66V.  This is within spec of the PIC.  If Vdd = 3.3V, you will need to scale appropriately.

As far as the interface method, you have a few options:

1. The HLVD module.  This would work just fine, and has the benefit of "set-and-forget". Once it is configured, you just wait for an interrupt.
2. An analog input. This also works, but you'll need to regularly sample the input.
3. If the scaling works out, you may be able to simply use the horn signal as a digital input!  Make sure that when the signal goes low that it is below the \$V_{IL}\$ of the PIC, found on page 335 of the datasheet.

**However**, you'll need to add some extra protections.  The power systems of automobiles are very noisy and hard to deal with.  You can get false triggers, and large voltage spikes when starting the engine that can damage your microcontroller.

By the time you account for these things the circuit can become considerably more complicated.  See some of the other answers. @tcrosley even shows how to create a safe, filtered Vdd for the PIC!

Good luck :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a circuit which will provide a digital input to your microcontroller, and also provides a filtered power supply for your microcontroller.

[image]

Transients can be nasty on a vehicle's 12V system, with voltages rising as high [as **125v** for 10 ms during a load dump](http://www.eet-china.com/ARTICLES/2003MAY/PDF/2003MAY26_POW_AN04.PDF).

This circuit provides protection against negative voltages in addition to the positive spikes due to load dumps, noise, and jump starting.  I have used an LDO regulator for simplicity, but you can substitute a switcher if you want for that block.  The Zener diode protects the voltage going into the regulator from going over the 26V maximum.

The horn circuit uses a comparator to generate a digital signal which indicates if the horn is operated.  The 1000 µF capacitor will smooth out any noise from getting into the microcontroller and make handling of the signal simpler.  The circuit uses a voltage divider to cut the nominal 12v horn voltage to 4/14 or 29% of its value.  So 14V (typical car system voltage) will appears as 4V, and 12V as 3.43V.  The other side of the comparator is connected to another voltage divider which provides a 2V reference.  A Zener is provided to limit the voltage going into the comparator to 4.7V.

Answer (score 3):

Bitsmack has provided an excellent description of why you're seeing that voltage drop, but it's also one reason I'd avoid doing what you're proposing of relying on that voltage drop because it might not be reliable in the longer term. For example say it's a mechical relay and fails one day you might find when replaced the internal and external contact resistance is much lower so you start getting a much lower voltage drop. Also if you move your circuit to other vehicles they will have different characteristics as well.

To handle that and some of the other nasty characteristics automotive systems can have I'd consider using an optocoupler instead. In this circuit I've calculated the resistor so that when subjected to a 125 V load dump it will fall within the 50 mA limit of the LED in the optocoupler and the 1N4148 provides some reverse voltage protection for the LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXBVET.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above assumes you can access the positive side that runs to the horn, but should be more reliable than trying to detect the voltage difference to ground and will keep your microcontroller input line isolated from voltage spikes on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

I think more robust alternative on bitsmacks answers is to use zenner diodes. Arranged as per below these will serve 2 purposes.

D1 will provide a constant voltage drop, this will eliminate the effect of the "On" resistance of the switch.

D2 In combination with the R1 limits the voltage to 3.3v and deals with any nasty automotive spikes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvD1UP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As a bit of a side-note the disadvantage to this circuit is a constant draw when the horn is off, this can be minimized by increasing R1, however the datasheet will need to be checked as zenner diodes are specified at a certain current.

Comment: The Vdd for the PIC18F4520 is 5V, not 3.3V (from the datasheet).

Comment: Missed that but the premise is identical, just pick a 5v zenner diode